# DB2 Connection Issue using JDBC from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, db2

I need to connect to a DB2 database server using `jdbc` from Eclipse. Even though I have already installed the required jar file, I am getting the following error:

```
Error occurred java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Error occurred java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://db2server
```

What do I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the JAR containing com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is in your CLASSPATH.
2. If it is, check the URL syntax.  That error usually means that the driver class was loaded, but the URL was incorrect.  [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0512kokkat/#connect) are the docs to show you what the correct syntax is.
3. If both of those look right, make sure that the server name is visible from your machine.  Ping that machine name; find out that you have it in your hosts table.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

Well I tried to download [IBM Driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html) and the Downloaded folder also contains **db2jcc.jar** and **db2jcc4.jar** put both these jars in **WEB-INF/lib** folder all do add them in classpath (Build path options). also your code must look something like this,

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();

        //context
        //DataSource datasource = null;
    //  datasource = (DataSource)initCtx.lookup("jdbc:sqlserver://AZNICSQL02;DatabaseName=CIO;schemaName=dbo");


        //Connect to Data source
        dbconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://192.168.4.58:50001/", "", "");
        dbstatement = (Statement) dbconnection.createStatement();`
```

Try exploring in **DataSource Explorer plugin** in eclipse